# Chaining SQLite call in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, asynchronous, race-condition

I am chaining SQLite call in phone gap to achieve synchronousity, like so:

```
db.transaction(initDB, errorCB, function() {
                db.transaction(lookupContactDB, errorCB, function() {
                    db.transaction(contactUpdateDB, errorContactCB, function() {
                        db.transaction(lookupUpdatedDB, errorUpdateCB, function() {
                            updateRiders();
                        })
                    })
                })
            });
```

However it is clear that the success callbacks are returning our of order. How can this be, when the next transaction should only start when the previous one's success callback to called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't be making a new transaction inside other transactions in this case. What you probably want instead, is to make the SQL executions there. So something like this might be a better flow

```
db.transaction(initDB, errorCB, function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("YOUR QUERY", [], function(tx, results1) {
        tx.executeSql("SECOND QUERY", [], function(tx, results2) {
            tx.executeSql("THIRD QUERY", [], function(tx, results3) {
                updateRiders();
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Now what happens is the following:

1. Transaction is acquired,
2. *"YOUR QUERY"* is executed,
3. when that data is fetched, *"SECOND QUERY"* is executed,
4. when that data is fetched, *"THIRD QUERY"* is executed,
5. when that data is fetched, *updateRiders* is called.